# parse pandas column into multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe which I wish to parse column that have the following stracture:

```
'._config.test_dataset_config.train = False'
'}'
'- INFO - trainer - Iter #8000 - iteration: 0.77s - forward: 0.43s - loss: 0.034s - loading_wait: 0.15s - backward: 0.16s - parallel_loading: 8.1s (0 Failed) - train_loss: 6.12e-03'
```

I wish to parse it to:

```
iter, forward, loss, loading_wait
Na, Na, Na, Na
Na, Na, Na, Na
0.77, 0.43, 0.034, 0.15
```

Is there an easy way to do it?

I can use the following:

`df = pd.read_fwf('log_file_date_2023_06_08_time_16_34.log', header=None, colspecs=[[0,16],[17,-1]], parse_dates=[0], names=['time', 'rest'])`
but then I need to specify the start:end of each column and it causes errors when the lines doesn't have the desired structure. (I want to apply the parsing only to the rest column)

Comment: One option would be to read it into a single column and use [Series.str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split on `-` with `expand=True` and then remove the extra columns